# How to import CSV file (LOAD CSV) from a remote location?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have my CSV data stored on a server that can be accessed via the internet. There is no authorization needed for access to that file. At the moment, I use `scp` and some crone jobs to copy that file to my Memgrpah server. Then I import data using `LOAD CSV`.

Is there a way to do something like `LOAD CSV FROM "https://my-server.com/files/state.csv" NO HEADER AS row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `LOAD CSV`:

```
LOAD CSV FROM <csv-location> ( WITH | NO ) HEADER [IGNORE BAD] [DELIMITER <delimiter-string>] [QUOTE <quote-string>] [NULLIF <nullif-string>] AS <variable-name>
```

`<csv-location>` can be used for `http`, `https` and `ftp` based URLs.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it is not possible to import remote files into Memgrpah using `LOAD CSV`. There is an [issue opened on GitHub](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/290) repo so the solution should be available at some point.